# Uncaught ReferenceError: ProductMediaManager is not defined easylife switcher magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed easylife switcher in magento. Everything is working fine except the image is not showing correctly. It is zoomed image and I am unable to zoom in or zoom out.
I have selected the option of switch all media section as switch main image is not working at all.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by myself after struggling with the code. There is nothing wrong with easylife switcher. The thing is that according to your theme you have to add code. So for generating thumbnails in my theme bxslider was used. So, I just initialized that along with existing code in JS callback.